# Difference between different type of caches and their significance

Tags: caching, ehcache, google-guava-cache

What is the difference between the Ehcache and Guava Cache? In which scenarios would I use which type of caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am a developer working on Ehcache

The answer to your question depends on which features your cache needs to have inside your application.

- [Guava caches](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) have all the basic caching features.
- Ehcache has more advanced features - see [2.x line](https://ehcache.org/documentation) or upcoming [3.x line](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3)

  - Multi tier caching (disk in 2.x, offheap + disk in 3.x)
  - Clustering (2.x for now, soon in 3.x)
  - Refresh ahead or scheduled refresh (2.x for now)
  - JSR-107 API

So my advice is to look at your needs, play with both and then decide.